# User model declarative authorization 'if_attribute' issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, declarative-authorization

I am using authlogic (2.1.3) and declarative_authorization (0.4.1) to control access to my application.

All of the authorization works as expected *except* user's that are assigned the Editor role can't change their (the current_user supplied by authlogic) profile settings (a part of the User model).

The 'Guest' role works as expects, as does the 'Administrator'.

I am using a User (named 'bob') that has been assigned the Editor role.  Verified in the database and in an IRB session.

Relevant contents of authorization_rules.rb file:

```
  role :guest do

    # allow anonymous 'user' to create an account
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:new, :create]

    # allow anonymous 'user' 'read-only' actions
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:index, :show]

  end

  role :editor do

    # allow authenticated User to see other users
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:index, :show]

    # allow authenticated User to update profile; doesn't work
    has_permission_on :user, :to => [:edit, :update] do
       if_attribute :user => is { user }
    end

  end

  role :administrator do

    # 'full control'    
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  end
```

I believe that the problem relates to the if_attribute :user => { user }.  if_attribute seems to suggest that the :user should be an attribute (or property) of the thing being tests, in this case a User model, rather than being the thing itself.  I looked for an if_self method or something similar, but I didn't see anything.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution; it did related to the if_attribute method as I suspected.  The correct role setting is:

```
role :editor do

  # allow authenticated user to see other users
  has_permission_on :users, :to => [:index, :show]

  # allow authenticated user to update profile
  has_permission_on :users, :to => [:edit,:update] do
    if_attribute :id => is { user.id }
  end

end
```